# insert prepared statement in database with parameters

Tags: jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

in my code I'm using a prepared statement to insert with 7 parameters :

```
connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1,"31/07/12");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1);
preparedStatement.setInt(3, 2);
preparedStatement.setInt(4, 3);
preparedStatement.setInt(5, 4);
preparedStatement.setInt(6, 4);
preparedStatement.setFloat(7, 6);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

it actually work this way and the row is inserted, but whenever i try to bind a parameter to a variable such as:

```
int i = 1;
preparedStatement.setInt(6, i);
```

it doesnt work during the execution, the thread is endlessly waiting without error and no row is inserted. 
However if the row already existed I still get a exception unique constraint.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of you code that is failing.  Seeing it in complete context might help.  Also, you say the thrad is endlessly waiting.  I assume you mean one of the JDBC calls above is not returning to the application?  If that's a false assumption then can you explain what exactly is waiting?

Comment: Hi Bruce I found the issue. My table was somehow locked and so the behaviors i described was just a coincidence I guess

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  If the JDBC driver you are using supports QueryTimeout you might want to set it so your app does not wait indefinitely for this time of operation to complete while waiting on table locks to clear.